# This Bazel build file has only deps no srcs

Tags: bazel, mediapipe

I was trying to use google's media pipe but this Bazel build has no srcs only deps. What is supposed to be the main program in this build?

```
package(default_visibility = ["//mediapipe/examples:__subpackages__"])

cc_binary(
    name = "hand_tracking_tflite",
    deps = [
        "//mediapipe/examples/desktop:simple_run_graph_main",
        "//mediapipe/graphs/hand_tracking:desktop_tflite_calculators",
    ],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "hand_tracking_cpu",
    deps = [
        "//mediapipe/examples/desktop:demo_run_graph_main",
        "//mediapipe/graphs/hand_tracking:desktop_tflite_calculators",
    ],
)

# Linux only
cc_binary(
    name = "hand_tracking_gpu",
    deps = [
        "//mediapipe/examples/desktop:demo_run_graph_main_gpu",
        "//mediapipe/graphs/hand_tracking:mobile_calculators",
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [cc_binary docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/3.3.0/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary)  deps defines list of libraries linked to this binary target. First dependency of each rule defines a library with the main function. You can see this looking at first dependency definition:

`mediapipe/examples/desktop/BUILD:`

```
cc_library(
    name = "simple_run_graph_main",
    srcs = ["simple_run_graph_main.cc"],
    deps = [
#... removed for clarity.
    ],
)
```

Therefore main is defined in `mediapipe/examples/desktop/demo_run_graph_main.cc`

Hope it helps ;)